# automatically merged branches in Git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I use this command in Git:

```
git checkout -b test1
```

and then come back again in master branch using

```
git checkout master
```

and then I type this command to see the unmerged branches:
    git branch --merge

and the test1 appears in the result but I haven't merge it to master yes. It seems it merged it automatically. It happens for any branches I make.

Why is it so?

Why do somebody vote my question as a off-topic ? Git is a version control tool and so my question is related to programming.

Comment: @the one who voted to close: this question is not off-topic, it covers a software tool commonly used by programmers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Lets assume your `master` branch is pointing at commit `C2` (refer diagram).

[image]

2) When you execute `git checkout -b iss53`, GIT will create a new branch `iss53` which points to the same commit.

[image]

Here the HEAD of the `iss53` branch [`C2`] is reachable from `master`. So, logically they are merged.

3) if you commit something to `iss53` branch, it would become like this.

[image]

Now the commit `C3` won't be reachable from master. `git branch --merged` would no more show the branch `iss53`.

Comment: Thank you Karthik. I commit something to test1 and it is no-merge now.

Comment: @hd. you are welcome. Added images for better understanding.. ;-)